# If two different diseases have more than one common pathway, the relationship between their occurences?

Tags: molecular-biology, pathway

I just wonder that are there any special relationship between the pathway and disease occurrence.

For example, there are cancer A and cancer B (and they have more than one common pathway). Then if one person was diagnosed with cancer A, does he have a high probability for getting cancer B? Could you recommend any researches for that?

Comment: I think that a good point to start is a classic work in literature that i've seen cited many times in my courses: http://www.cell.com/abstract/S0092-8674(11)00127-9